# Why is the Prüfer sequence in a labeled tree always unique?

Tags: graph-theory

The [Prüfer sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) (also Prüfer code or Prüfer numbers) of a labeled tree is a unique sequence associated with the tree.

[image]

as we can see from the picture there is a unique sequence {4,4,4,5} #
 but how can we prove that it is unique for a particular tree ?

Edit: Extracting from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) on Prüfer sequences, the Prüfer sequence of a labeled tree is defined as follows:

> One can generate a labeled tree's Prüfer sequence by iteratively
>   removing vertices from the tree until only two vertices remain.
>   Specifically, consider a labeled tree T with vertices {1, 2, ..., n}.
>   At step i, remove the leaf with the smallest label and set the ith
>   element of the Prüfer sequence to be the label of this leaf's
>   neighbour.

Comment: Yes, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) clearly says it's unique.

Comment: It seems like your question is *why* is the code unique for the tree? Referring also to wikipedia :) ... "Somewhat less obvious is the fact that for a given sequence S of length n–2 on the labels 1 to n, there is a unique labeled tree whose Prüfer sequence is S."

Comment: Yes, but why it is unique

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you, I have aupdated !

Comment: The Prüfer sequence of a labeled tree is ***obviously*** unique, because it is defined by a deterministic algorithm; if you input the same labeled tree again, you are sure to get the same output. The more interesting question, ***which you have not asked***, is why a given Prüfer sequence corresponds to a unique labeled tree.

Answer (score 5):

The uniqueness of the prufer sequence comes from the fact that the trees are reconstructable.

For example, with $\{4,4,4,5\}$
The first number not in the code is $1$, so we attach vertex $1$ to $4$(the first entry in the code) now drop the $4$ from the code and add a $1$ to the back to get $\{4,4,5,1\}$.

The first number not in the code is $2$, so attach $2$ to $4$, drop the $4$ and add $2$ to the back to get $\{4,5,1,2\}$.

The first number not in the code is $3$, so attach $3$ to $4$, drop the $4$ and add $3$ to the back to get $\{5,1,2,3\}$

The first number not in the code is $4$, so attach $4$ to $5$, drop the $5$ and add $4$ to the back to get $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Now we have exhausted the entire original code. The final step is to add an edge between the two numbers not shown in our new code, so attach $5$ to $6$.

This will give you back the original tree. Since we have a way to "Uncode" the prufer code, it is unique.

Comment: Do you know a formal proof?

Comment: The original algorithm with the reconstruction algorithm gives you a function and its inverse from labelled trees on $n$ vertices to sequences of length $n-2$ using $1$ through $n$ as the entries. Thus the prufer algorithm is a bijection and thus 1-1. Does that help? If not, try to expand on where you are lost and I will try to help.

Comment: @FawziBelal do you not understand the original algorithm, the reconstruction algorithm or something else?

Comment: Thank you 
I understand the example, but since it is just an example, I prefer the solution to be: formal rather than proof by example.
What you have explained: "Prüfer Code" is unique as you claim that it is comes from the construction "is this proof by construction"?
again : what is the point "formally" that guarantee that Prüfer Code => gives always "one" Labeled Tree!?

Comment: The fact that there is a way to decode the tree from the sequence doesn't alone prove it is unique. Imagine a code similar to the Prüfer code but where each vertex $i$ in the code is either labelled $2i$ or $2i+1$. We can reconstruct a tree given this new code, but the code is not unique. You also need a unique way to construct the code from the tree, which we have for the Prüfer code.

Comment: @MichaelMior Sure, but uniqueness follows here because there is a unique way to go from the tree to the code, then a way to go back. Of course, if you change it so that there is not a unique way to go from a tree to the code, there is more work to be done. The unique way to go from tree to code gives us an injection from trees to codes. Showing there is a way to reverse this process gives us that this is also a surjection, and thus a bijection. This is equivalent to showing uniqueness of codes.

Comment: @SeanEnglish Agreed :)